# SQL delete query on non key column

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm new to the SQL query language and I'm trying to figure out how to delete a row (in a SQL DB table) with a non key ID column value using vb.net.  For example in the table TEST below:

```
ID     Name 
1      x 
2      y 
3      z
```

I have a windows form that the user selects the Name value, however when I run my code it says

> *Cannot convert varchar "y" to int.*

Here is my code attempt:

```
Dim sConnectionString As String

sConnectionString = "Data Source=" + serverName + ";Initial Catalog=" + dbName + ";Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Dim objConn As New SqlConnection(sConnectionString)
objConn.Open()

Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

cmd.Connection = objConn
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TEST WHERE Name = y"

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Thank you!

Comment: you need to add the y in quotes, cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TEST WHERE Name = 'y'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your Name column is of type varchar you need to enclose the value in single quotes

```
cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TEST WHERE Name = 'y'"
```

A complete answer to your question will be:

```
Dim sConnectionString As String 
sConnectionString = "Data Source=" + serverName + _
                     ";Initial Catalog=" + dbName + _ 
                     ";Integrated Security=SSPI;" 

Dim objConn As SqlConnection
Using(objConn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString) 
    objConn.Open() 
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand 
    cmd.Connection = objConn 
    cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TEST WHERE Name = @name" 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
End Using
```

I'm supposing that your user insert the name to delete in a textbox and you pass this value to a parametrized query. The use of parametrized query will save you from the hassle to handle quoting problems and from Sql Injection Attacks

Answer (score 3):

If you do this you will be deleting all rows `WHERE Name = y` and you probably don't want to do that.

You should use the name in the UI but pass the ID to SQL.

If you really do want to delete ALL rows with that name then put quotes around the y, as without them it's looking for a column named y:

`DELETE FROM TEST WHERE Name = 'y'`

Answer (score 0):

cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TEST WHERE Name = y";

instead you can use this one

cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TEST WHERE ID = " + idValue;

here the 'idValue' is the ID that u take from the user

OR OTHER WISE

cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM TEST WHERE Name = 'y'";